# How to use UI.getCurrent().navigate("route") inside Mono.subscribe

Tags: java, vaadin, webclient, vaadin-flow

```
  public void onAlfrescoTicketReceived(Mono<Ticket> ticket) {
    ticket
        .log()
        .subscribe(
            consumer -> {
              this.sessionService.setTicket(consumer.getTicket());
              UI.getCurrent().navigate("route");
            });
  }
```

The sessionService works but UI.getCurrent returns null. Is there a way to navigate inside a subscribe?

Comment: UI.getCurrent() returns null when called outside http request thread. If this call is in your component you can do getUI().ifPresent(ui -> ui.navigate("route"))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably executed in a background thread. `UI.getCurrent()` only works within the UI thread.

You need to store a reference to the UI at a point where you are still in the UI thread, or by calling `getUI()` on an attached component. If your method is executed in the UI thread then you can store the reference there. Then you call `UI#access` to execute any UI tasks:

```
public void onAlfrescoTicketReceived(Mono<Ticket> ticket) {
    UI ui = UI.getCurrent();
    ticket
        .log()
        .subscribe(
            consumer -> {
              this.sessionService.setTicket(consumer.getTicket());
              ui.access(() -> ui.navigate("route"));
            });
}
```

Using `UI#access` when calling from a background thread ensures the session is locked, so that there won't be any conflicts in the UI state. It also ensures that `UI.getCurrent()` and `VaadinSession.getCurrent()` returns the correct values.